# How can I create screen using piped command

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, gnu-parallel

i'm trying to open a new screen for a command which using pipe.
I have tried many options e.g:

```
screen "cat ~/input | parallel --colsep '\t' -j 100 -m sh ~/runner.sh {}"
```

Maybe i'm missing something with file descriptors or something, but searching efforts were in vain.
Thanks.

Comment: `screen` accepts a single command to run; but that command can be e.g. `sh -c 'parallel .... <$HOME/input'`. (Notice also how this isn't `screen` accepting anything from a pipe, and how the useless `cat` can be avoided.)

Comment: It does work, but just to understand, if I join those two commands using {} 
screen {cat ~/input | parallel --colsep '\t' -j 100 -m sh ~/runner.sh {}}
why it still doesn't work?

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but if you want to join two commands together into a compound one, you actually must have spaces surrounding the curly braces and a semi-colon after the second command, i.e. `{ command1; command2; }`

Comment: What about piped commands?

Comment: You are making unfounded assumptions about how the shell and `screen` cooperate to parse your command line. Short answer: they don't. You cannot use shell syntax within the `screen` command line, except with a workaround like the one I showed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly use shell syntax constructs like `{ code; }` or `;` or `&` or `|` in arguments you pass to `screen` (or `parallel`, or `xargs`, or etc).  The shell will try to parse your command before running it, so anything which looks like

```
echo | moo |
```

will be parsed into a pipeline with the commands `echo` and `moo` and nothing (which is of course a syntax error).  If you want to `echo` a pair of literal pipe characters, you have to quote them:

```
echo '| moo |'
```

If you want the quoted stuff to be evaluated *after* the shell parses it, there are a couple of options.

- Encapsulate the command externally in a script, so that you can say `screen myscript` and have the actually useful commands in the script file `myscript`. (Some useful tools even allow you to use shell functions or even aliases here.)
- Pass the command `sh -c 'morecommands'` or `bash -c 'morecommands'` so that the commands are quoted but end up being executed anyway.  This is just another form of encapsulation really, but doesn't require a separate external definition like a script file or shell function.

So in your example, you could put your code in a script like `./metarunner` and then just call `screen ./metarunner`; or quote the command line like

```
screen sh -c "parallel --colsep '\t' -j 100 -m sh $HOME/runner.sh {} <$HOME/input"
```

(I switched `~` to `$HOME` here so I could use `sh` instead of `bash`. If you need nontrivial Bash features or are too lazy to refactor your code into POSIX shell script, obviously use `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`.  See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) for what the differences are exactly.)

Tangentially, I also got rid of the [useless use of `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)